# The Monster PolyLog Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{Li_n(-\sigma x)Li_m(-\omega x^2)}{x^3}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, contest-math

I am trying to solve this integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}
{{\rm Li}_{n}\left(-\sigma x\right){\rm Li}_m\left(-\omega x^{2}\right)
 \over x^{3}}\,{\rm d}x
$$
 which is from some high school training courses from many years ago.  We have $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\sigma,\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, $|\arg \sigma| <\pi, |\arg \omega| <\pi $.  I am stuck as to where to start.  Thanks.  The polylogarithm function is given by
$$
Li_n(z)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{z^j}{j^n}, \ (|z| \leq 1).
$$

For $|z|>1$ we can use the analytical continuation result given by
$$
Li_n(z)=(-1)^{n+1}Li_n(z^{-1})-\frac{1}{n!}\ln^n(-z)-\sum_{j=0}^{n-2}\frac{1}{j!}(1+(-1)^{n-j})(1-2^{1-n+j})\zeta(n-j)\ln^j(-z)
$$

Comment: High School ???.

Comment: @FelixMarin Yes. Is it odd for high school students to be challenged like this?  Come to Plovdiv, Bulgaria if so.  We studied advanced integration techniques with older students and the city high school teachers while preparing.  This was during the early 80's.  I'm sure you know, but the late 80's all of a sudden literature boomed in this area of integration.